# Jquery Mobile size is too small

Tags: html, css, mobile, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm making an app on PhoneGap using Jquery Mobile. The app runs fine on the PC browser and on the simulator, but when I install it on my phone everything is very small.

On my home page I have a listView that is searchable, and when I tap the textfield to search something the page adjusts to a more readable size.

How can I solve this? I want it to be readable from the start.

Comment: Doesn't it get too heavy for mobile devices?

Comment: No it does not. It runs just fine.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Add this in the `<head>` of your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

It will scale the page to fit your device size.

Comment: @bobek i wonder if this setting is suitable to cover all type of mobiles with different OS platform?

Comment: @ggDeGreat It should be because it's based on the browser and not OS platform. All it does is it stretches or shrinks the page to match the width of the window.

Comment: This is really great. Would you please also explain how each attribute work in this case?